# How were cheats for the GTA games on PC found?

Tags: gaming-history, grand-theft-auto-series

I Googled around a lot but came across only 1 such example where some guy tried combinations (permutations?) on his PS2 controller. But that does not give me the reason how the ones on PC are found.

So, does Rockstar release them or are they just present in the game such that game programmers can open and see while modding or something else?

Comment: Dont get the downvotes.Could someone point out improvements? I know this seems like a dumb question but I have seen so many on this site which could just be found by googling and they were received well.But I could not find anything by googling about this.

Comment: Also If anyone knows how were they found for PS3 and Xbox360 also?But primary question is for PC.

Comment: I don't understand the downs either so at the risk of losing rep i'll put this in a comment:Cheats are often passed out to different places by the developers themselves, cheat are created in the first place as a means of testing games, most other cheats that don't serve a testing purpose get added in for the fun of the player, often when cheats aren't given out by developers directly, you do get the lucky person who encounters it and can reproduce it, and some that hunt for them by just mashing buttons, and others that do dig through code on PC to find names and references that point to cheats

Comment: It's important to note that 'cheats' are different from 'hacks' or actual cheaters in multiplayer games. Maybe people think you are asking about hacks that change gameplay in ways developers never intended or added in themselves, that's different form cheat codes like in GTA where you can get all weapons via a button sequence but not in GTA Online.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer So is  there a possibility for the newer GTA games like GTA 5 that there are some cheats which are still undiscovered ? I would like to think so because I remember in San Andreas there were two codes for the same effect and one was found quite later.

Comment: Yes i believe it is very possible that there are undiscovered cheat codes, after all the whole bigfoot/peyote thing was just recently brought to a conclusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways a cheat can be found for a game.

- The developer can send the information to a website or magazine for "exclusive rights" to some cheats and tricks - this was largely used in the 90s;
- The game can be [datamined](https://www.engadget.com/2014/04/10/what-is-data-mining-and-why-is-everyone-talking-about-it/), and as such, getting the secrets in the code revealed by the dataminers;
- They can be found randomly, as you said on your question, a player can try combinations until something works.

There's no way we can guess how it worked for the specific situation of GTA, but we can try to have an idea from those possibilities.